# How to make a perfect pinch zoom (Unity 3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, zooming, pinchzoom, perspectivecamera

I am searching for a solution to how to make a perfect pinch zoom in Unity by moving the camera along the forward:

Set up:
Horizontal plane centred at the origin with all Game objects.
Perspective camera with FOV 10, offset at (10,10,10) looking down at a 45 degrees angle, so that it looks at the origin (there is also a rotation of 45 degrees around the axis pointing up, to achieve this).

What I need:
When I place two fingers on the screen I am touching two GameObjects with them - so the screen coordinates under the fingers correspond to certain world coordinates. When I make a pinch movement (with moving two fingers or only one) I want the new screen coordinates to correspond to the same world coordinates that were under the fingers at the beginning of the whole interaction.
So to simplify even further - whenever I touch the screen with two fingers, I want the world coordinates corresponding to the screen coordinates under my fingers to always stay under the fingers (allowing a very small margin of error).

An example of this perfect zoom for which I am looking for you can see in the mobile game Boom Beach from Supercell.

I already tried to move the camera along its forward vector and to reposition it and I get pretty good results, but pretty much always the GameObjects underneath ‘slip’ away from under my fingers, that is at some points are no longer underneath them. It would be great if there was a mathematical solution to this, but if it’s necessary to compute the answer (through some search for example) then this is totally fine.

If the setup/scenario is not clear, I could provide some sketches to clarify it a bit more.

Hope someone can help me! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would set up a system that detects when the user is zooming in and out if you are using GameObjects to pinpoint where the fingers are that is easy to do with Vector3.distance. After that, I would make a function that moves the camera closer to your desired zoom level with Vector3.MoveTowards(camera position, desired position, the speed of movement) where I would set "speed of movement" as a mathf.sqrt(vector3.distance(Camera position, Desired position));
as for the "desired position" I would set that Vector3(position) as a fraction of a line between two game objects that represent your maximum and minimum zoom level.
EDIT: with that, you should have a very nice camera system